# How could I call a JavaScript function to autoplay a slideshow with the following call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider having three slides and its a four boxes slideshow. It breaks the 1st image into four and then the next image comes up. On the click of the next button the current image breaks up and the next image comes up. it works fine on click but i would like to automate this transition of the images. I tried using setInterval function of javascript but it didn,t work fine. I have this code from codrops and i am trying to integrate the same in my website. Please help me as I am new to jquery. I also saw a similar post but it didn't work.
Following are the codes of HTML and js file.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>Four Boxes Slideshow | Demo 2</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Four Boxes Slideshow: Recreating the background image slideshow seen on Atelier Serge Thoroval's website" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="background slideshow, boxes, background image, four panels, css, tutorial" />
    <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div id="boxgallery" class="boxgallery" data-effect="effect-2">
            <div class="panel"><img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Image 3"/></div>
            <div class="panel"><img src="img/4.jpg" alt="Image 4"/></div>
            <div class="panel"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Image 1"/></div>
            <div class="panel"><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Image 2"/></div>
        </div>
        <header class="codrops-header">
            <h1>Four Boxes Slideshow <span>Recreating the background image slideshow seen on <a href="http://www.atelier-serge-thoraval.com/en/">Atelier Serge Thoroval's website</a></span></h1>
            <nav class="codrops-demos">
                <a href="index.html">Serge Thoroval</a>
                <a class="current-demo" href="index2.html">Lateral</a>
                <a href="index3.html">Fall</a>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div><!-- /container -->
    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/boxesFx.js"></script>
    <script>
        new BoxesFx( document.getElementById( 'boxgallery' ) );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**boxesFx.js**
This is the jquery code thay needs to be looked upon.

```
;( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

    // based on http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/
    function getViewport(axis) {
        var client, inner;
        if( axis === 'x' ) {
            client = docElem['clientWidth'];
            inner = window['innerWidth'];
        }
        else if( axis === 'y' ) {
            client = docElem['clientHeight'];
            inner = window['innerHeight'];
        }

        return client < inner ? inner : client;
    }

    var docElem = window.document.documentElement,
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
            'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions },
        win = { width : getViewport('x'), height : getViewport('y') };

    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    function BoxesFx( el, options ) {   
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this._init();
    }

    BoxesFx.prototype.options = {}

    BoxesFx.prototype._init = function() {
        // set transforms configuration
        this._setTransforms();
        // which effect
        this.effect = this.el.getAttribute( 'data-effect' ) || 'effect-1';
        // check if animating
        this.isAnimating = false;
        // the panels
        this.panels = [].slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( '.panel' ) );
        // total number of panels (4 for this demo)
        //this.panelsCount = this.panels.length;
        this.panelsCount = 4;
        // current panel´s index
        this.current = 0;
        classie.add( this.panels[0], 'current' );
        // replace image with 4 divs, each including the image
        var self = this;
        this.panels.forEach( function( panel ) {
            var img = panel.querySelector( 'img' ), imgReplacement = '';
            for( var i = 0; i < self.panelsCount; ++i ) {
                imgReplacement += '<div class="bg-tile"><div class="bg-img"><img src="' + img.src + '" /></div></div>'
            }
            panel.removeChild( img );
            panel.innerHTML = imgReplacement + panel.innerHTML;
        } );
        // add navigation element
        this.nav = document.createElement( 'nav' );
        this.nav.innerHTML = '<span class="prev"><i></i></span><span class="next"><i></i></span>';
        this.el.appendChild( this.nav );
        // initialize events
        this._initEvents();
    }

    // set the transforms per effect
    // we have defined both the next and previous action transforms for each panel
    BoxesFx.prototype._setTransforms = function() {
        this.transforms = {
            'effect-1' : {
                'next' : [
                    'translate3d(0, ' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)', // transforms for 1 panel
                    'translate3d(-' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)', // transforms for 2 panel
                    'translate3d(' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)', // transforms for 3 panel
                    'translate3d(0, -' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)' // transforms for 4 panel
                ],
                'prev' : [
                    'translate3d(' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)',
                    'translate3d(0, ' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                    'translate3d(0, -' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                    'translate3d(-' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)'
                ]
            },
            'effect-2' : {
                'next' : [
                    'translate3d(-' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)',
                    'translate3d(' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)',
                    'translate3d(-' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)',
                    'translate3d(' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)'
                ],
                'prev' : [
                    'translate3d(0,-' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                    'translate3d(0,-' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                    'translate3d(0,' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                    'translate3d(0,' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)'
                ]
            },
            'effect-3' : {
                'next' : [
                    'translate3d(0,' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                    'translate3d(0,' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                    'translate3d(0,' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                    'translate3d(0,' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)'
                ],
                'prev' : [
                    'translate3d(0,-' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                    'translate3d(0,-' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                    'translate3d(0,-' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                    'translate3d(0,-' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)'
                ]
            }
        };  
    }

    BoxesFx.prototype._initEvents = function() {
        var self = this, navctrls = this.nav.children;

        navctrls[0].addEventListener( 'click', function() { self._navigate('prev') } );

        navctrls[1].addEventListener( 'click', function() { self._navigate('next') } );

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', function() { self._resizeHandler(); } );
    }


    // goto next or previous slide
    BoxesFx.prototype._navigate = function( dir ) {
        if( this.isAnimating ) return false;
        this.isAnimating = true;

        var self = this, currentPanel = this.panels[ this.current ];

        if( dir === 'next' ) {
            this.current = this.current < this.panelsCount - 1 ? this.current + 1 : 0;          
        }
        else {
            this.current = this.current > 0 ? this.current - 1 : this.panelsCount - 1;
        }

        // next panel to be shown
        var nextPanel = this.panels[ this.current ];
        // add class active to the next panel to trigger its animation
        classie.add( nextPanel, 'active' );
        // apply the transforms to the current panel
        this._applyTransforms( currentPanel, dir );

        // let´s track the number of transitions ended per panel
        var cntTransTotal = 0,

            // transition end event function
            onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( ev && !classie.has( ev.target, 'bg-img' ) ) return false;

                // return if not all panel transitions ended
                ++cntTransTotal;
                if( cntTransTotal < self.panelsCount ) return false;

                if( support.transitions ) {
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                }

                // remove current class from current panel and add it to the next one
                classie.remove( currentPanel, 'current' );
                classie.add( nextPanel, 'current' );
                // reset transforms for the currentPanel
                self._resetTransforms( currentPanel );
                // remove class active
                classie.remove( nextPanel, 'active' );
                self.isAnimating = false;
            };

        if( support.transitions ) {
            currentPanel.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
        }
        else {
            onEndTransitionFn();
        }
    }

    BoxesFx.prototype._applyTransforms = function( panel, dir ) {
        var self = this;
        [].slice.call( panel.querySelectorAll( 'div.bg-img' ) ).forEach( function( tile, pos ) {
            tile.style.WebkitTransform = self.transforms[self.effect][dir][pos];
            tile.style.transform = self.transforms[self.effect][dir][pos];
        } );
    }

    BoxesFx.prototype._resetTransforms = function( panel ) {
        [].slice.call( panel.querySelectorAll( 'div.bg-img' ) ).forEach( function( tile ) {
            tile.style.WebkitTransform = 'none';
            tile.style.transform = 'none';
        } );
    }

    BoxesFx.prototype._resizeHandler = function() {
        var self = this;
        function delayed() {
            self._resize();
            self._resizeTimeout = null;
        }
        if ( this._resizeTimeout ) {
            clearTimeout( this._resizeTimeout );
        }
        this._resizeTimeout = setTimeout( delayed, 50 );
    }

    BoxesFx.prototype._resize = function() {
        win.width = getViewport('x');
        win.height = getViewport('y');
        this._setTransforms();
    }

    // add to global namespace
    window.BoxesFx = BoxesFx;

} )( window );
```

Comment: I would use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or the equivalent to get the ID of the element that you click to get the next frame. Then I would use `setInterval` to click the element periodically.

Answer (score 2):

In `BoxesFx.prototype._initEvents = function(){...}` add `setInterval(function(){ self._navigate('next') }, 4000);`. This will slide your image after every 4 seconds.